# MongoDB $filter doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

This is my projection stage of aggregation:

```
Document filter = new Document(
                            "$filter", new Document(
                            "input", "$joins").append("as", "join").append(
                            "cond", "{$eq: [\'$$join.exited\', false]}"));
list.add(project(new Document("_id", 0).append("joins", filter).append("userName", 1)
                                             .append("chatID", 1).append("warned", 1)));
```

But it returnes elements from `joins` which their `exited` is set to `true` (and also `false`).
Can you tell me what is my mistake?
(I should mention that `list` is an `ArrayList` of aggregation stages)

**EDIT.** This is one document I expect:

```
{
    userName: "test",
    //other fields than joins
    joins:
    [
        {
            remaining: 4
            userID: 1245
            exited: false
        },
        {
            remaining: 3
            userID: 2312
            exited: false
        }
    ]
}
```

I want `exited` to be false all the time.

Comment: Can you add the sample doc you are expecting the query to return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the document value as it is getting interpreted as literal string value.

Update

```
"cond", "{$eq: [\'$$join.exited\', false]}")
```

to

```
"cond", Document.parse("{$eq: [\'$$join.exited\', false]}")
```

or

```
"cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$join.exited", false))
```

Both variants should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks